# Excel Solver Integer Constraint

Tags: excel, optimization, integer, solver

I am trying to optimize the number of shifts needed for a workday and I am trying to use Solver in order to optimize my solution. It works without an integer constraint, however I do want to use integer constraints on my shifts because I want full shifts, not fractions of a shift. How do I fix that? Can I fix that in excel or should I move to python instead? (Which I’m more familiar with)

The variables that solver can change are the number of shifts started at each hour of a day. So 24 variables.

I have optimized my solution but with fractional variables. I want integer variables.

Comment: Then you may need to relax some constraints like "equal to" to "less than or equal to" , same for greater than.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could add some picture of the Solver`s paramaters. Usually it is enough to choose int in constraints windows.